# Fill null values in simple dataframe with sum of surrounding values

Tags: python, pandas, null, fillna

I am looking to compute null values 'inside' a dataframe. Basically, each of the boundary 'cells' of this dataframe contain a value, and all the interior values are null.

So I want to fill these null values by summing the surrounding 4 cells and dividing by 4, such that the value at any given cell is h i,j = (1/4)(h i-1,j + h i+1,j + h i, j-1 + h i, j+1).

| Col0 | Col1 | Col2 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 95 | 90 | 85 |
| 95 | NaN | NaN | 80 |
| 90 | NaN | NaN | 75 |
| 85 | NaN | NaN | 70 |
| 80 | NaN | NaN | 65 |
| 75 | 70 | 65 | 60 |

I am unsure how to iterate over this dataset and apply the above formula.

My expected output, based on my Excel version of this:

| Col0 | Col1 | Col2 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 95 | 90 | 85 |
| 95 | **90** | **85** | 80 |
| 90 | **85** | **80** | 75 |
| 85 | **80** | **75** | 70 |
| 80 | **75** | **70** | 65 |
| 75 | 70 | 65 | 60 |

My initial idea was to to use the following loop:

```
for i in df:
        i.fillna(
(i[:, :, 1:] + i[:, :, :-1] + i[:, :-1, :] + i[:, 1:, :])/4, inplace=True
)
```

I.e. fill each NaN value with the sum of the four surrounding cells divided by four.

But this doesn't work, it just returns 'cannot unpack non-iterable int object'

Does anyone have an idea of how I can
(a) Correctly develop a formula to access all surrounding cell values; and
(b) How to actually apply this to calculating these values?

I can do this straightforwardly in Excel which allows you to iterate this type of calculation relatively easily, but I am struggling to conceptually transfer it to Python.

I tried the above code, but it doesn't work and I can't apply my conceptual understanding to Python well.

Comment: can you post the expected calculated df?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Done - thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input csv as below:

```
Col0,Col1,Col2,Col4
100,95,90,85
95,NaN,NaN,80
90,NaN,NaN,75
85,NaN,NaN,70
80,NaN,NaN,65
75,70,65,60
```

And given the desired output csv as below:

```
Col0,Col1,Col2,Col4
100.0,95.0,90.0,85.0
95.0,95.0,88.3,80.0
90.0,92.5,85.3,75.0
85.0,88.8,81.3,70.0
80.0,79.6,72.7,65.0
75.0,70.0,65.0,60.0
```

This is the code:

```
import sys

with open('input.csv', 'r') as file:
    lines1 = file.readlines()

lines2 = []

for x in range(len(lines1)):
    lines1[x] = lines1[x].strip()
    if len(lines1[x]) > 0:
        lines2.append(y.strip() for y in lines1[x].split(","))

header_list = list(lines2[0])

lines2 = [[float(x) if x != 'NaN' else None for x in inner_list] for inner_list in lines2[1:]]

row_index_exceeded = len(lines2)
column_index_exceeded = len(lines2[0])

def generate_neighbours(row_index,column_index):
    global row_index_exceeded
    global column_index_exceeded
    return_list = []
    if row_index-1 != -1:
        return_list.append([row_index-1,column_index])
    if row_index+1 != row_index_exceeded:
        return_list.append([row_index+1,column_index])
    if column_index-1 != -1:
        return_list.append([row_index,column_index-1])
    if column_index+1 != column_index_exceeded:
        return_list.append([row_index,column_index+1])
    return return_list

def process_list_of_lists(input_list):
    for row_index in range(len(input_list)):
        for column_index in range(len(input_list[row_index])):
            current_cell = input_list[row_index][column_index]
            if current_cell == None:
                neighbours = generate_neighbours(row_index,column_index)
                num_values = 0
                sum_values = 0
                for x in neighbours:
                    if input_list[x[0]][x[1]] != None:
                        num_values = num_values + 1
                        sum_values = sum_values + input_list[x[0]][x[1]]
                if num_values == 0:
                    print("Critical error. Top-left cells require values.")
                    sys.exit()
                input_list[row_index][column_index] = float(sum_values/num_values)
                return input_list

while True:
    break_inner_loop = False
    for x in range(len(lines2)):
        for y in lines2[x]:
            if (y == None) and (break_inner_loop == False):
                lines2 = process_list_of_lists(lines2)
                break_inner_loop = True
    if break_inner_loop == False:
        break

with open('output.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.write(','.join(header_list)+"\n")
    for x in lines2:
        y = [f'{num:.1f}' for num in x]
        file.write(','.join(y)+"\n")

print("Execution complete. Check output csv file.")
```

This is different from your sample output because I am not sure of the logic of your sample output.